# What is the proper way to check if the sql code is working correctly?

Tags: sql, database

After writing an `sql` statement with multiple joins I asked myself how I could test whether my code is working correctly.

I get some results but how can someone be sure that there are no entries missing?

One could look up in the table if all entries are there. But what if there are thousands of entries or the statement is just too complex for the human brain? I guess there must be some kind of standard or something like that to verify `sql` codes.

I googled but did only find some services that verify the syntax which is not what i am searching for.

How is this handled in the professional `sql` developer world?

Comment: You can't test every possible case. What you can do is to select a "smart" subset of tests, and use an automated tool to run this subset. Later on, when you make changes you can run the all the automated tests again (in seconds or minutes) if needed.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you

Comment: If the human brain can write the query, then the human brain can check if it worked regardless of the data don't you think?

Comment: You can't test every possible case as @TheImpaler already said I would like to add that we usually have the objectives which that sql statement is written for as long as it fullfils that requirement it should be good

Comment: There are a lot of ways to test your data,like data driven testing,I suggest you take a look at this link to find out which kinds of tests is suitable for you, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/index.htm, I hope it helps